# LG G3 (d852), no OS, not loading into TWRP

Tags: adb, root-access, twrp

So I have been having troubles with my ROMs, and I decided to format everything to clean it up and do a fresh install. PC wasn't copying rom zip to the device, so I tried to use ADB Sideload and push the zip through that. Something happened on the Device's side, and I cancelled it, but it wasn't going back or finishing. I took a risk and pulled the battery, but now the phone boots up into the LG Logo boot screen, but does nothing from there. I am unable to boot into recovery from there, as if the buttons don't work. PC doesn't connect to the device, so I am unable to boot into recovery via ADB. Does anyone have suggestions or is the device completely bricked?

edit: phone's LEDs starts cycling colours after a few minutes, and device manager detects something, refreshes, but nothing comes up. I'm assuming these LEDs mean that the phone is trying to boot, but can't boot into anything due to no OS installed. ADB still doesn't detect any devices, and I am still unable to get into TWRP from here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like corrupted OS than no OS; try to boot into recovery by 1: remove battery 2: put battery back in, and power up by pressing both power button and vol up button 3: when you see LG logo release the buttons and immediately press them again to boot into recovery 4: perform a factory reset to clear corrupted files. 5: reboot.

Comment: I'm still unable to get into recovery using these tips. Screen just stays at the LG logo, unresponsive.

Comment: I'm sorry I seem to have mixed up the key combination. For your device, it seems to boot into recovery mode with power + vol down instead of vol up. Give it a go with this one.

Comment: power and volume down doesn't work either. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you get into download mode?

Comment: Haven't tried this before, and it does get into download mode. What can I do from here? Sorry for nooby questions.

Comment: http://www.modifyandroid.com/stock-roms/lg/how-to-flash-stock-rom-for-lg-g3/ follow this guide but be sure to use firmware for your model here ( http://lgg3root.com/lg-g3-stock-factory-firmware/ ) the link in the guide 
doesn't seem to work. If you use network locked phone, find their firmware. Use the CSE method, it will wipe your data but you will probably salvage your phone.